# bootstrap-vue checkbox selecting all or none

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, bootstrap-vue

I am attempting in Vue to create a form s.t. a user can check one or more of a series of stacked checkboxes to select one or more options.

I am currently unable to select/unselect options one by one. I either have to select the entire array or none of them.

Here is my input html:

```
<b-form-group label="Individual stacked checkboxes (default)">
        <b-form-checkbox
          v-for="option in options"
          v-model="selected"
          :key="option.value"
          :value="option.value"
          name="flavour-3a"
        >
          {{ option.name }}
        </b-form-checkbox>
      </b-form-group>
      <button class="btn btn-success" @click="assignGroups">Accept Assignments</button>
```

And here is the data structure:

```
data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      options: [
        { item: 'A', name: 'Option A' },
        { item: 'B', name: 'Option B' },
        { item: 'C', name: 'Option C' },
        { item: 'D', name: 'Option D' }
      ],
      notification: {
        message: '',
        type: ''
      }
    };
  },
```

Here is the documentation I am attempting to follow: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `key` and `value` props does not correspond to your `option` structure.

You need to change `:key="option.value"` to `:key="option.item"` and `:value="option.value"` to `:value="option.name"`

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      options: [{
          item: 'A',
          name: 'Option A'
        },
        {
          item: 'B',
          name: 'Option B'
        },
        {
          item: 'C',
          name: 'Option C'
        },
        {
          item: 'D',
          name: 'Option D'
        }
      ]
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-group label="Individual stacked checkboxes (default)">
    <b-form-checkbox v-for="option in options" v-model="selected" :key="option.item" :value="option.name" name="flavour-3a">
      {{ option.name }}
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </b-form-group>
  Selected : {{selected}}
</div>
```